# Program to eat up all of my CPU please (Windows)

Tags: windows, cpu, exe

I know it might sound like an odd question, but theres a logical explanation behind me doing so, very long story.

So could someone provide a program which will eat up as much of my CPU as possible please, preferably .exe files please

Comment: If you are looking for people to hand you executable programs without you having to so much as examine the contents yourself, SO really isn't the right place for you. Questions here need to be about programming or software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered a [*fork bomb*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)?

Comment: The nice thing about fork bombs is that they still work the same in a parallel computing environment.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the long story - I need a bit of diversion from real development.

Create as many 'while true do;' threads as there are cores. Raise them to real-time priority.  Set them running. Stand by the power switch.

EXE?  You're 'avin a larrf!  DIY.

Rds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the following C code on Windows and run it to eat up all CPU.
https://www.electronproton.com/cpu-mem-load-test/

Note that the above one only eats up single core.
If you want to eat up all multi-cores in your system then use OpenMP threaded program. You can download it from the below link.
https://www.electronproton.com/multi-core-cpu-and-memory-load-test/